# Vue.js blocks Rails UJS' ajax:success callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, ujs

I am using UJS and Vue on the same page and have discovered that there is a conflict. While the JSON still loads via AJAX, Vue takes over the Rails UJS callback and prevents it from firing. UJS is great for dynamic links to APIs. Vue has its obvious benefits too.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ujs/1.2.2/rails.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="main">

  <a class="load-ujs" href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" data-remote="true" data-method="get" data-type="json">Load JSON via UJS link</a>

  <p class="result-ujs"></p>

</div>

$('.load-ujs').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
  $('.result-ujs').text(xhr.responseText);
});

// Uncomment the following block and click the link again to demonstrate
// how Vue, once instantiated, conflicts with UJS ajax:success callback

/*
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  data: {
    number: 1
  }
});
*/
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/vVjLjB

What's the best way round this?

(If we can sort this out, the next problem will be working around getting UJS to process an href directive - ie. v-bind:href="'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + number" - which I know it can't.)

Comment: if you move the `.on(...)` binding below the Vue code, the success callback is triggered, I don't know if that creates other problems though

Comment: Nice to know. Admittedly not the most robust solution, though.